# fetch data from database to components

Tags: phpmyadmin, components, joomla2.5

i have one issue i am installing components and i want to add that components one new field add in back end side and more i want to do add new field in back end side that field is drop down list i want to add and i want to fetch data from database in drop down

give me any suggestion what to do that my problem solve and you tell me where to write dat query  in components tell me specific file name  i have code and i add my code as under below

Trying to get property of non-object in **C:\wamp\www\Joomla\administrator\components\com_home_service\views\serviceitem\tmpl\edit.php** on line **84**

```
<form action="<?php echo JRoute::_('index.php?option=com_home_service&layout=edit&id=' . (int) $this->item->id); ?>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="adminForm" id="serviceitem-form" class="form-validate">
    <div class="width-60 fltlft">
        <fieldset class="adminform">
            <legend><?php echo JText::_('COM_HOME_SERVICE_LEGEND_SERVICEITEM'); ?></legend>
            <ul class="adminformlist">

                                <li><?php echo $this->form->getLabel('id'); ?>
                <?php echo $this->form->getInput('id'); ?></li>
                <li><?php echo $this->form->getLabel('image'); ?>
                <?php echo $this->form->getInput('image'); ?></li>
                <li><?php echo $this->form->getLabel('image_name'); ?>
                <?php echo $this->form->getInput('image_name'); ?></li>
                <?php
                    //defined('_JEXEC') or die('Restricted access');
                    $db = JFactory::getDBO();
                    $query=$db->getQuery (true);
                    $query->SELECT ('*');
                    $query->from('#__content');
                    $db->setQuery( $query);
                    $results = $db->loadObjectList();?>
                     <li><?php echo $this->form->getLabel('image_name'); ?>
                    <select>
                            <option value="<?php echo $result->id; ?>">1</option>

                       </select></li>

            </ul>
        </fieldset>
    </div>
```

give me clue for that problem

i want to do fetch other table data fetch in drop down list wht to do and tell me right query ..

Answer (score 1):

You can define function in model file of the table which returns data and include that return value to show in dropdown

```
In controller:
      $model2 = & $this->getModel('modelname');
      $view->setModel($model2, false);
In view.html.php  
      $model2 = & $this->getModel('modelname');
      $droplist = $model2->functioname();
      $lists ['dropdown'] = JHTML::_('select.genericList', $droplist , 'fieldname', 'class="inputbox validate-notzero"', 'value', 'text');
In default.php
      <?php echo $lists ['dropdown']; ?>
```

Hope this will help to solve your problem.